# How to make a popup open on click?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to hang an event by clicking on the button to open the popup. 
How to create the boolean function `openPopup` in index.ts

```css
.window__container {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 102px;
        top: 100px;
        min-width: 360px;
        height: 528px;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
```

```html
<button md-icon-button (click)="!openPopup"></button>
<div *ngIf="openPopup" class=.window__container>...</div>
```

Comment: Is it really @input(), or is it just a typo? Just asking since it should be @Input()

Comment: @saglamcem, thanks, I fixed

Comment: I meant to ask if that's the same way in your code, too. :) Also, I found that you're trying to run a function over an input you received a bit questionable. Could you explain your logic by also sharing how "openPopup" was injected into this component?

Comment: @saglamcem, 
I don't know how it should look is really :(

Comment: No problem. Tell me why you thought about using the @Input() pattern, and let's try to figure out what might be working unexpectedly. :)
It would also be helpful if you could share your code (or part of it) on stackblitz or a similar site, so we can debug things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place you code in mentioned files.

At first while using **class** you don't have to use `.window__container` just use `window__container`.

On Click Button Set `openPopup` status.

**HTML** file

```
<button md-icon-button (click)="openPopup = !openPopup">Open</button>

<!--If you want to use click function then -->

<button md-icon-button (click)="openPopup()">Open</button>
<div *ngIf="openPopup" class=window__container>
  <h1>Hello Popup</h1>
</div>
```

**TS** file

```
openPopup: boolean;

// If Want to use Function for popup
openPopup (): void {
 this.openPopup = !openPopup;
}
```

**SCSS** File

```
.window__container {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 102px;
        top: 100px;
        min-width: 360px;
        height: 528px;
        z-index: 10000;
        background: red;
```

}

In css class i just put the `background`.

Comment: thank you so much. you can help me yet? close popup when clicking on overlay in your version code